# column names are dropped when converting a df from pandas to PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a json file in below format.

```
{
  "fd": "Bank Account",
  "appVar": [],
  "varMode": "AABH",
  "occurred": [
    {
      "occurredTimes": 3,
      "sys": [
        {
          "varTyp": "Conf Param",
          "varCode": "P33"
        }
      ],
      "userAssignments": []
    }
  ]
}
```

My existing code is developed in pandas but I need to convert the same code to be running on PySpark. For this purpose I'm using [Pandas API on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html) API.
As per the API, I'm trying to read a JSON from file and convert the Pandas df into a PySpark df as below.

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import pandas as pd

df_pandas = pd.read_json('./demoFile/in/all.json', orient='values')
df_pyspark = ps.DataFrame(df_pandas) # ps.DataFrame([df_pandas])
```

I need to get the `occurred` array as it is after the conversion as well. But it returns,

**Expected Output:before conversion**

```
[{'occurredTimes': 3, 'sys': [{'varTyp': 'Conf Param', 'varCode': 'P33'}], "userAssignments": []]
```

**Output : after conversion**

```
[(3, [Row(varTyp=,'Conf Param', varCode=,'P33',)], [])]
```

How can retain the column names while converting pandas df into a PySpark df using above API?

Comment: I get an error with this JSON: `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`. Shouldn't `fd` and `varMode` be also lists?

Comment: you can make the orient `index` instead of `values`. `pd.read_json('./demoFile/in/all.json', orient='index')`

Answer (score 0):

You can change this column with `to_json`, e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json

df_pyspark = df_pyspark.withColumn("occurred", to_json("occurred"))
```

gives for `ocurred` column:

```
[{"occurredTimes":3,"sys":[{"varTyp":"Conf Param","varCode":"P33"}],"userAssignments":[]}]
```

In case it fails with your code, try to create the PySpark dataframe with a schema before:

```
json_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("fd", StringType(), True),
        StructField("appVar", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
        StructField("varMode", StringType(), True),
        StructField(
            "occurred",
            ArrayType(
                StructType(
                    [
                        StructField("occurredTimes", IntegerType(), True),
                        StructField(
                            "sys",
                            ArrayType(
                                StructType(
                                    [
                                        StructField("varTyp", StringType(), True),
                                        StructField("varCode", StringType(), True),
                                    ]
                                )
                            ),
                            True,
                        ),
                        StructField("userAssignments", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
                    ]
                )
            ),
            True,
        ),
    ]
)
```